# Retrieve characters labels from a vector

Tags: r

I have created a numeric vector using tapply(characters,numbers,sum) which looks like this (just a sample below):

```
a c d or f e ar fu bar
1 5 9 1  1 1 1   1  1
```

Now i need to retrieve the character labels on another vector. Any ideas?
The original character vector contains multiple instances of the characters, so I'm not sure how much use it will be.

Desired output a vector with the characters listed:

```
a c d or f e ar fu bar
```

I thought that objects such as these could be accessed using some simple command since they are embedded so to speak into the numeric vector, but alas haven't been able to find this function. as.character() just gives me the numbers in character format.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, add desired output and show what you have tried? I can't tell what you are trying to do. May be `?names`

Comment: @JakeBurkhead - almost certainly just `names(x)`

Comment: Just to clarify what's the difference between a vector with names attached to it and a factor with levels attached to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want 'names':

```
names(tapply(characters,numbers,sum))
```